# Customise function name and arguments (in the `.getString()` for instance)

Tags: javascript, function

#### tl;dr:

I want to edit how a function looks like. for example, when you `console.log` in in Firefox or Chrome, I want to edit the arguments and name we see, and also edit the `.length` and `.name` properties. Is that possible ?

#### The longer version :

I want to copy and customize the execution of a given function, by adding instructions before and after. My code looks like this:

```js
function customizeFunction(funcToCustomize) {
    return function(...args) {

        // Some instructions, for example :
        console.log('Calling', funcToCustomize.name);

        // The function itself
        let returnValue = funcToCustomize.call(this, ...args); 
                          // Or simply funcToCustomize(...args) if you prefer
        
        // Some instructions if call terminates :
        console.log('success, no error encountered during call');

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

I've tested it with this in the Firefox console :

```
let original = function (x,y) {
    console.log(x+y);
};
let custom = customizeFunction(original);
custom(2,3);

/* Output :
Calling original  
5  
success, no error encountered during call debugger eval code:12:17  
undefined
*/
```

It works as intended. But whenever I do :

```
console.log(custom);
```

It outputs `function customizeFunction(args)` (whereas `original` outputs `function original(x,y)`). Is there some properties I can change to make is output `function original(x,y)` or `function custom_original(x,y)` ?

Also, `original.length` is 2 whereas `custom.length` is 0. Can I also change this ?

Comment: the function does not return anything

Comment: @epascarello If you talk of `customizeFunction`, it returns another function (see second line of code). I've tested this code and it works fine. I just want to edit the name and the apparent arguments of the created function `custom`.

Comment: If you talk of `original` it doesn't matter if it returns something or not. What is important is that `custom` acts like `original`, with the only difference of the logs before and after the function's execution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the toString method of returned function

```
function customizeFunction(funcToCustomize) {
    let customFunc = function(...args) {

        // Some instructions, for example :
        console.log('Calling', funcToCustomize.name);

        // The function itself
        let returnValue = funcToCustomize.call(this, ...args); 
                          // Or simply funcToCustomize(...args) if you prefer
        
        // Some instructions if call terminates :
        console.log('success, no error encountered during call');

        return returnValue;
    }

  customFunc.toString = function () {
    return funcToCustomize.toString();
  }

   return customFunc;
}
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't change `console.log(custom)`'s output on Chrome and Firefox, because it is a reference of the function that is logged : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

But otherwise, it works, indeed !